# Not able to prevent from clicking past days in v-calendar (vuetify)

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vcalendar

i've implemented a v-calendar base on the vuetify docs , but i'm not able to disable the click event for the past days so the user can't create events in the past days , thanks

Comment: you should share your relevant code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

You need to check a event and if event start date < today, do return

But also you can do it before push to events
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/calendars/#drag-and-drop

Comment: Please, don't post image for code, but code as plain text.